# Else Statement Is Being Bypassed

Tags: python, function, if-statement, pycharm

Using Python, 3.9 to build a collection I have come across the following problem:

```
def displayItemFromDescription(self, desc):
    print()
    if desc not in self.items:
        print('Sorry, that item category does not exist. Please try again.')
    else:
        print('Items for description:', desc, '\n')
        print('{:<30s}{:<21s}{:<8s}{:<5s}'.format('Description', 'Category', 'Value', 'Amount'))
        print('-' * 65)
    for item in self.items:
        if item.desc == desc:
            item.display()
```

Expectation A: If the user enters a category that does not match categories in self.items, they will receive a "Sorry, that item category does not exist..." message. This works just fine.

Expectation B: The user enters a valid category and a category menu is displayed with correct format. This works just fine.

The problem is that the "else" statement seems to be bypassed. The "if" statement and the "for" loop are printing together. This is not the expected outcome.

This is the displayed message at the moment:

> Sorry, that item category does not exist. Please try again.
>
> Watch              Antique      450.00      1

Any and all suggestions are welcomed. I am new to programming and will try to answer your questions as best I can.

Comment: Does your for loop execute under `else`? If so, the indentation of `for` is wrong. It needs to align with `print` above so that it is part of the else block. At present, the for loop will execute regardless of the if condition

Comment: Hello Nick. The `for` loop does execute under `else` without the print statements above the `for` loop. I indented the `for` loop to align with the `print` above and but no luck. It repeatedly states "Sorry, that item category does not exist..." as if the `else` statement was not even there.

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption that "self.items" is some standard python container, e.g. list or a tuple

`if desc not in self.items`

will check if any of the items equals desc, as in

```
item == desc
```

However from your code it looks like what needs to be "equal" is in fact the .desc field

```
item.desc == desc
```

for this to work you will have to do one of the following:

- change the datastructure so that items holds descs, and not objects
- declare own equality operator for items, which defines how to compare an item to description
- declare your own `__contains__` for your container that alters how "in" works

Comment: I think OP is noting that the "if true" block and the for block are executing together, and that this is not expected.

Comment: indeed, and they are printed together because, as stated in the answer, they use different comparisons